# Unable to revive computer from suspend mode in Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, suspend, power-management, thinkpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Thinkpad E440. Though I generally don't use Suspend option, but whenever by mistake I select that option, my laptop goes to low power state as expected. But my laptop is not able to wake up (tried every key on keyboard) and I have to shutdown the laptop by pressing power button and reboot my laptop. Is there a specific set of keys I need to press to wake up my laptop?

Comment: The same trouble on Dell Vostro

Comment: Does your machine have a blue key with a moon on the keyboard?

Comment: NO there is no such key@Fabby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable USB 3.0 Mode from BIOS. It worked for me.

Comment: Yes it also seems to have worked for me. But WHY?

Comment: Actually our hardware isn't fully supported. I have also problem with brightness interface.